# Android : How to Get "serviceAccountCredentials.json" File Path

Tags: android, json, firebase

Following snippet requires
"path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"

Kindly give me an example of where to place
the ".json" file in android app folder and
adding its path in snippet.

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

I have followed below link :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#initialize_the_sdk

Comment: You are referring the **SERVER** Link.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

> copy config file into your project's module folder, typically app/

Comment: Yes, did the same but what will be the "path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"?

Comment: It is the same process as we used to do in GCM. I guess you are referring the server link. Which in case of android app should refer to the my answered link.

Comment: Actually I am creating demo Android App (acts as a server) which will generate the token. Thus referring SERVER link.

Comment: Then you should put your file path on the server where you are putting the serviceAccountCredentials.json. If you are doing it in java then you should use your server file path where you have put the file. It is something which you do not need to put in android app.

Comment: Ahhh... This seems to be helpful.. Thank You .. :)

Comment: Accepted. But marking will not be visible to others as I don't have 15 Reputations.

Comment: @VarshaP Where did you put this file?